# React Router - History - Where does it store state object?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

```
this.props.history.push({
                    pathname: '/created',
                    state: {created_id: this.state.id}
                });
```

What is state here?
Will it work in all the browser?
Where does react stores it?

I wanted to ask this question in react discuss. But they put the post in pending and unable to discuss this there.

Comment: are you using browser history (e.g. `BrowserRouter`)?

Comment: Yes. `<BrowserRouter><Layout /></BrowserRouter>`. I am making an app which only for mobile. So i want to target almost all mobile browsers.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer is that react-router uses the [history](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history) module, which in turn uses the browser's history api.  If supported, state is stored in memory by the [browser's history api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_pushState()_method). If not supported, then the [history](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history) module [stores the state](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/blob/master/modules/createBrowserHistory.js#L42).

Answer (score 2):

> What is state here?

Not exactly sure I understand the question? The state is just `{created_id: this.state.id}`, no?

> Where does react stores it?

React Router utilizes [History](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history) which stores the state in your browser's standard history object: `window.history`.

> Will it work in all the browser?

Yes, `window.history` has been supported by all major browser versions for years. [See CanIUse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=history) for more detail.

---

What exactly are you trying to accomplish, though? There is definitely more than one way to skin a cat when it comes to React Routing...

So, maybe some open discussion is a healthy thing here. Just try to keep it brief in comments. S/O is not technically meant for discussion.

Comment: `axios.post('create', data).then( response => { this.props.history.push ... })` once a post is created by the user, i want to sent the user to created component with post id.

Comment: What is the context here (where is that call fired from in relation to the routed component)? Are you using Redux? If so, the action you are firing that from will not be "connected". The easiest workaround here is to pass `this.props.history` as an argument to the Redux action. This will let you reference the connected component's `props` instead of the Redux action's non-existent one.